# Как я могу делать запросы на сайт, пока не получу результат?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно делать запросы на сайт до того момента, пока я не получу результат. Как только это было сделано, цикл прекращается. В чем моя ошибка?

```py
import datetime, requests

date = datetime.date.today()
while True:
    response = requests.get("https://api.site.com/earth/photos?earth_date=" + str(date))
    json = response.json()
    if json["photos"] == []:
        date = date - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
    else:
        print(json)
        break
```

Comment: @SergeyGlukhov вставил. Все равно цикл не хочет останавливается. Делается запрос, получается валидный результат, но `break` будто не работает.

Comment: Значит у вас условие `json["photos"] == []` выполняется всегда. Добавьте `print(json)` перед `if` и посмотрите что вообще приходит.

Comment: @insolor как-то так: `{'photos': []}`.

Comment: Если так все время приходит, то и выход из цикла не происходит

Comment: @insolor так там же есть условие, что в ином случае я получу другой результат. И он появляется, но цикл не хочет останавливаться. В этом вся проблема.

Comment: Как выглядит json, когда приходит результат?

Comment: @insolor тут весь результат не поместиться, поэтому вот: https://textuploader.com/ts5ya.

Comment: Этот json выводится в какой-то момент при работе цикла?

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Сойдёмся на этом? :-) Раз цикл не завершается, значит оператор *break* не срабатывает. Раз он не выполняется, значит условие json["photos"] == [] не выполняется **никогда**. Просто вставьте первым оператором в обе ветки *if* операторы *print('Yes')* и *print('No')*. Сразу всё станет ясным.

Comment: @Sergey наверно опечатка. Вы имели ввиду, что условие `json["photos"] == []` выполняется **всегда**

Comment: @RomanKonoval Да, разумеется!